# The orbit of a compact Lie group action

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, group-actions

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on a manifold $M$. For each $p\in M$, we define the orbit of $p$ as $G\cdot p:=\{g\cdot p: g\in G\}$. The isotropy group of $p$ is $G_{p}=\{g\in G:g\cdot p = p\}$. I read in many sources that $G\cdot p$ is diffeomorphic to $G/G_{p}$, though I could not find a clear proof.
I see that there is a well-defined bijection
$$\phi: G/G_{p}\rightarrow G\cdot p: gG_{p}\mapsto g\cdot p.$$

Can someone explain why this is in fact a diffeomorphism?

Comment: Question from a fellow student of geometry and lie theory. By definition, the underlying manifolds are smooth and the various conditions for the accompanying atlas are satisfied. since $\phi$ is a bijection, between smooth manifolds then it is a diffeomorphism yes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The map is smooth because we can construct it by passing the smooth map $G \to G_p$ via the natural quotient map $G \to G / G_p$. It follows immediately from the definitions of the two group actions that the map is equivariant. Thus, it has constant rank, and any bijective, smooth map of constant rank is a diffeomorphism. (See $\S$9 of Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds* (1st ed.) for more; this statement is essentially the content of Theorem 9.24 there. Possibly the relevant numbering is different in the current, second edition.)

Comment: It's Theorem 21.18 in the second edition.

Answer (score 2):

This is a consequence of the slice theorem of Koszul

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slice_theorem_%28differential_geometry%29